# map resource reference to resources in WAS6

Tags: jakarta-ee, jndi, ibm-was, websphere-6

In my EAR containing a WEB module and an EJB module I am trying to map EJB resources in WAS6 using ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi. While installing EAR it  ask for datasource mapping in **Map resource reference to resources**.[image] my question is While installing the EAR if i give a different JNDI name then will it change contents of **ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi** ? Also while installing EAR if i do some settings or configuration changes where i can see them i.e path {WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/config or ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems that the *bnd* files are changed when you change the Resource Reference mappings.

You can test it by exporting the application from the console and opening it with a zip tool.
When you install an application:

- The original EAR file together with deployment options is located in:

> WAS_PROFILE_HOME/config/cells/CellName/applications/AppName

- After the installation is finished the Application archives (the EAR & WARs) are extracted in the following place and used by the WAS Server from there:

> WAS_PROFILE_HOME/installedApps/AppName